# Which price to set, if there is not (yet) a price?

Tags: price

In Magento it is not possible to set a price = 0.

But there might be cases where data is not yet complete (when developing a shop) - or products are not for sale (i.e. some custom block is displayed)

What is a reasonable value to set as price?

I think a very high one if more secure than 0.01 ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not possible to set a price = 0'? I am able to create a product with price 0 without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't leave the price field blank because your product will not pass a JS validation but putting a "0" should work fine.

Otherwise you have some customisations which are not allowing to do so.

Comment: But 0-value products can still be sold? Just want to have a different between "No Price" and "Free Product"

Comment: Oh, that was unclear from the question. Then just put your product stock to 0 and then allow display of products w/o stock in catalog.

Answer (score 0):

For now I will use `88888888.88` and made a config class to define & return this price.